# Make appear a paragraph and make it disappear when showing the next one on click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new at Javascript and I am trying some very basic and simple exercise.

I have three paragraphs and at the click of the button I add a class .visible at one of them.

Now all it does is adding the class at the first loop and remove it at the second loop.
I want it to remove the class at previous paragraph when click again the button.

I know I have to tell to store the array index in a variable so at the second click at that index the class will be removed.

Can anyone help me please?

```
    <div>
        <p class="text">I am first</p>
        <p class="text">I am second</p>
        <p class="text">I am third</p>
    </div>

    <button value="click me" id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

const txt = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
let counTxt = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    appearTxt();
});

function appearTxt(){

    // count array
    counTxt = counTxt < txt.length -1 ? ++counTxt: 0;

    txt[counTxt].classList.toggle('visible');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't inderstant if you want to make appear the text of the selected paragraph or make them appear and disappear them progressively.

So, the answer to your question should be this one at my opinion:
Don't hesitate to comment if this is not the expected result.

Have a nice day.

```js
        const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

        const txt = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
        let counTxt = 0;

        btn.addEventListener('click',appearTxt1);

        function appearTxt1(e){
            for (var i=0; i<txt.length; i++){
                if((counTxt===i)){
                    txt[counTxt].className = "visible";
                }else{
                    txt[i].className = ("text");
                }
            }
            counTxt = counTxt < txt.length -1 ? ++counTxt: 0;
        };
// If you want to show the first text by default uncomment the line below 
        //appearTxt1();
```

```css
        .text{
            display:none;
        }
        .visible{
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
    <div>
        <p class="text">I am first</p>
        <p class="text">I am second</p>
        <p class="text">I am third</p>
    </div>

  <button value="click me" id="btn">Click me!</button>
```